# Number of dots in an image

Tags: computational-geometry, montecarlo

I have an image which has plain dots scattered across. The dots are of the same size and they are solid (I can read the color to decide whether a point is inside or not). What is the most efficient algorithm to find the exact number of the dots?
I thought of Monte Carlo, but I don't know the sufficient number of random points that I should use. Any advice?
Edit: it's a white image that contains dots only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good case for image processing algorithms.
For example, using OpenCV library, you could exploit the next approach:

If image format is color, convert it to gray scale (cvtColor)

Make image binary (pure black and white) with color inversion (cvThreshold with THRESH_BINARY_INV) to make white spots on the black background

Find connected components (findContours) - after that contours.size gives you number of dots

If you don't want to use any libraries, key point is [connected components labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

The simplest way to make CCL for small dots - using of [Floodfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.

Make flood fill for background pixels, mark them  with 0.

Scan through all pixels. When you meet unmarked one (at X,Y), start new flood fill with next marker value K (1,2 etc).

After each floodfill return to the next coordinate (X+1,Y) and continue scanning.

The last K value is the number of spots.

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you

Comment: @D.Badawi I've added one more simple approach for counting (a kind of component labeling suitable for dots)